# Drop Down list null reference on postback ASP.Net Core 6 MVC

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have spent a lot of time trying to sort this out without any luck.

I have successfully created a drop down list and it populates the field and all is well. It even posts the record back to the database. But upon clicking the submit button I get a Null Reference error.

Any and all help would be very appreciated

Below is the Model Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace CISIII.Models

{



    public class Dropdownlist

    {

        public DateTime? DtmDate { get; set; }

        public List<Status_List>? Statlist2 { get; set; }

        public IActionResult? GetDetails { get; set; }

    }



    public class Status_List
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

    }



    public class UserDataModel
    {
        public string? Fname { get; set; }
        public string? Sname { get; set; }
        public string? Coname { get; set; }
        public string? Tel { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? Add1 { get; set; }
        public string? Add2 { get; set; }
        public string? Suburb { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? Pcode { get; set; }
        public string? Findus { get; set; }
        public string? Prod_cat { get; set; }
        public string? Question2 { get; set; }
        public string? Ddlindustry { get; set; }
        public string? Web { get; set; }
        public string? Statlist1 { get; set; }
        public string? Start_date { get; set; }
        public string? End_date { get; set; }



        public int SaveDetails()

        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=bhd-web2;User ID=**;Password=**;Database=***; Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");


            string query = "INSERT INTO Customers (fname, sname, coname, tel, email, add1, add2, suburb, state, pcode, " +
                "findus, prod_cat, question2, ddlindustry, web, status, start_date, end_date, entry_date) values ('" + Fname + "','" + Sname + "','" + Coname + "', " +
                "'" + Tel + "','" + Email + "','" + Add1 + "','" + Add2 + "','" + Suburb + "','" + State + "','" + Pcode + "','" + Findus + "','" + Prod_cat + "', " +
                "'" + Question2 + "','" + Ddlindustry + "','" + Web + "','" + Statlist1 + "','" + Start_date + "','" + End_date + "', getdate())";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return i;
        }


    }
}
```

Below is the Controller Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CISIII.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace CISIII.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        public IConfigurationRoot GetConnection()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();
            return builder;

        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            Dropdownlist multi_Dropdownlist = new Dropdownlist
            {
                 Statlist2 = GetStatusList()

            };

            return View(multi_Dropdownlist);
        }

        public List<Status_List> GetStatusList()
        {
            var connection = GetConnection().GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("CAS").Value;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id, description From status order by description asc;", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<Status_List> status = new List<Status_List>();
            if (idr.HasRows)
            {
                while (idr.Read())
                {
                    status.Add(new Status_List
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(idr["id"]),
                        Description = Convert.ToString(idr["description"]),
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();


                return status;
            }

            public IActionResult View1()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public IActionResult Privacy()
            {
                return View();
            }

        public IActionResult newcust()
        {

            Dropdownlist multi_Dropdownlist = new Dropdownlist
            {
               Statlist2 = GetStatusList(),

            };

            return View(multi_Dropdownlist);

        }
        [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult GetDetails()
            {


                UserDataModel umodel = new UserDataModel();

                umodel.Fname = HttpContext.Request.Form["fname"].ToString();
                umodel.Sname = HttpContext.Request.Form["sname"].ToString();
                umodel.Coname = HttpContext.Request.Form["coname"].ToString();
                umodel.Tel = HttpContext.Request.Form["tel"].ToString();
                umodel.Email = HttpContext.Request.Form["email"].ToString();
                umodel.Add1 = HttpContext.Request.Form["street_number"].ToString();
                umodel.Add2 = HttpContext.Request.Form["route"].ToString();
                umodel.Suburb = HttpContext.Request.Form["locality"].ToString();
                umodel.State = HttpContext.Request.Form["administrative_area_level_1"].ToString();
                umodel.Pcode = HttpContext.Request.Form["postal_code"].ToString();
                umodel.Findus = HttpContext.Request.Form["Findlist"].ToString();
                umodel.Prod_cat = HttpContext.Request.Form["Prodlist"].ToString();
                umodel.Question2 = HttpContext.Request.Form["question2"].ToString();
                umodel.Ddlindustry = HttpContext.Request.Form["ddlindustry"].ToString();
                umodel.Web = HttpContext.Request.Form["web"].ToString();
                umodel.Statlist1 = HttpContext.Request.Form["Statlist"].ToString();
                umodel.Start_date = HttpContext.Request.Form["start_date"].ToString();
                umodel.End_date = HttpContext.Request.Form["end_date"].ToString();
                int result = umodel.SaveDetails();

                return View("newcust");



            }


        }

    }
```

Below is the View

```
@model CISIII.Models.Dropdownlist
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New Customer";
}
<head>

        
        
        <table style="margin:0 auto;" >
                    <tr >
                    <td   ><label>First Name</label></td>
                    <td  >
                        <input class="field" id="fname" name="fname" TabIndex="1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td  ><label>Address</label></td>
                    <td  TabIndex="8">
                         <div id="locationField">
                        <input id="autocomplete"
                        placeholder="Enter your address"
                        onFocus="geolocate()"
                        type="text"/>
                        </div>

                        <td></td>
                       
                        </td>

          
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td  ><label>Surname</label></td>
                    <td >
                        <input class="field" id="sname" name="sname" TabIndex="2"/></td>
                    <td  ><label>Address 2</label></td>
                    <td  Width="8">
                        
                        <input class="field"  id="street_number" name="street_number" disabled="disabled" />
                       
                        <input class="field"  id="route" name="route" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Company Name</label></td>
                    <td><input class="field" id="coname" name="coname"/></td>
                       
                    <td><label>Suburb</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field" id="locality" name="locality" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Tel No</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field" id="tel" name="tel"  TabIndex="4"/></td>
                     <td><label>State</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="disabled"/>
                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Communication Details for the Client   -->
                <tr>
                    <td  ><label>Email</label></td>
                    <td><input id="email" class="field" name="email"  TabIndex="5"/></td>
                    <td><label>Post Code</label></td>
                    <td >
                        <input class="field" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" disabled="disabled"/>
                           
              </td>
                    <!-- OnTextChanged="date_insert" -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  ><label>Web</label></td>
                    <td >
                        <input id="web" class="field" name="web"  TabIndex="6"></td>
                    <td  ><label>Status</label></td>
                     <td>
                     <div id="Status" name="Status">

                       
                 </div>       
                 <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Statlist2, new SelectList(Model.Statlist2, "Description", "Description"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
                
           
        </div>
                 </td> 
                                </tr>
           
                     <tr >
            <td  ><label>Start Date</label></td>
                              <td >
                                
                        <input id="start_date" name="start_date" class="start_date">
                              
                          </td>

            <td ><label>End Date</label></td>
          <td >
              
                  <input id="end_date" name="end_date" class="end_date">
               
                          </td>
              </tr>

  <!-- Asking Questions of the client   --> 
    <tr >
        <td  ColumnSpan="4">
            <Label>How did you hear about Us</Label>
        </td>
           </tr>
                <tr >  
                    <td   >
                 <Label>Industry</Label>
        </td>
           <td  ColumnSpan="3" Style="" >
               <div class="col-md-3">
           

        </div>
         </td>   
  </tr>

                 <tr  > 
                     <td  >
             <Label>Product Category</Label>
    </td>
         
                     </tr>

                 <tr > 
                     <td  >
        <Label>Where did you find us</Label>
    </td>
      </tr>
  
<tr>
   <td  ColumnSpan="4" >
        <Label>Customer Notes</Label>
             </td>
          
        <td  ColumnSpan="4"  >
            <textarea id="question2" class="field" name="question2" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
               
             </td>     
        </tr>
     <tr>


 <td  ColumnSpan="2" ><input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" formaction="GetDetails" asp-page-handler="Submit"/>



     </td>
        
     </tr>          
                </table>
 </form>
   
     @section Scripts{

        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(function () {
        $(".form-control").chosen();
                   
        });

        </Script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            
           
            <script>
                
          $(".start_date").datepicker({ 
              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
              chanegMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              minDate: new Date(2019,01,01),
              maxDate: new Date(2032,01,01),
              
              
          });

          $(".end_date").datepicker({ 
              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
              chanegMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              minDate: new Date(2019,01,01),
              maxDate: new Date(2032,01,01),
              
              
          });
        
          
                      
        </script>
      }
```

The Error

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Home_newcust.ExecuteAsync() in newcust.cshtml, line 230

```
Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Home_newcust.ExecuteAsync() in newcust.cshtml

                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Statlist2, new SelectList(Model.Statlist2, "Description", "Description"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The view is expecting an instance of `CISIII.Models.Dropdownlist`.  You provide it one from the `Index` controller action and the `newcust` controller action, but not from the `GetDetails` controller action.  So the `Model` in the view is `null` and trying to reference `Model.Statlist2` produces an exception.